# Why camera2 supported preview size width always bigger than height?

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-screen

I'm working on a project which using camera2 API. When I get the list of supported output preview size using:

```
StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
Size[] choices = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
```

the output size list **always** return values which have width>height despite the fact that screen's width

When I use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` (or any similar method) to check width/height it's always return width

And based on the value I see that in 2 cases the width/height are likely swap their value. (w: 1920, h: 1080 preview size. w: 1080, h: 1920 screen size).

So what is the different between them? Please help me!

Comment: because the standard photo should be landscape,not portrait.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So what I should do is only swap width & height? Btw do you have any document about this? Please give me a link.

Comment: I don't think that there is a single document. I think that it is on the camera module hardware level. So each camera module has it's own document. But I think it is completely safe to consider the width is larger than height. Any case, you should determine the photo rotation by something else. For example by G-sensor, or current display orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera on phones is traditionally built for landscape orientation of the device. We use rotation  of 90° to display camera frames correctly when the device is held in portrait orientation.

Here is the detailed explanation: 
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#TaskOrientation

Comment: do you have any document about this? Please give me a link.